# XML-RPC struct in java

Tags: java

i want to create request xml-rpc struct in java, my code is like this

```
public String xmlprc() throws XmlRpcException, MalformedURLException{
    ReqModelTest req = new ReqModelTest();
    String test="";
    Object paramsR =  new Object(); 
    Vector params = new Vector();
    req.setvalue1("value1");
    req.setvalue2("value2");
    req.setvalue3("value3");
    req.setvalue4("value4");
    req.setvalue5("value5");
    params.add(req);
    XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl(); 
    try { 
        config.setServerURL(new URL("myurl")); 
        XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient(); 
        client.setConfig(config); 
        paramsR = (Object)client.execute("mymethod", params); 

    } catch (MalformedURLException | XmlRpcException e) { 
        log.info(e);
    } 
    log.info(paramsR.toString());
    test = paramsR.toString();
    return test;
}
```

but when i run it, it shows error `org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Failed to generate request: Unsupported Java type: com.model.ReqModelTest`. is there any way how to do it? Thank you very much

Comment: What is it ReqModelTest? Is this your class? You have an undefined clase "com.model.ReqModelTest". Check imports.

Comment: ReqModelTest is class which has getter setter in it @Grzesiek

Comment: If it is in import, it can, as described below, help adding serialization.

Answer (score 0):

The most common error we have in these cases is not implementing **`Serializable`** interface.

The documentation tells us to follow these steps :

- All primitive Java types are supported, including long, byte, short, and double.
- Calendar objects are supported. In particular, timezone settings, and milliseconds may be sent.
- DOM nodes, or JAXB objects, can be transmitted. So are objects implementing the **java.io.Serializable interface.**
- Both server and client can operate in a streaming mode, which preserves resources much better than the default mode, which is based on large internal byte arrays.

Please check you are following these guidelines.

http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom `TypeFactory` to handle your own data types.

Please see [this link](https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/advanced.html)